# Calculating a Matrix Norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to calculate some norm for a matrix $A = [3, 2; 0,1]$ given the formula $\|A\| = \max_{|v|=1}|Av|$, where $|v|$ is taken to be the Euclidean norm for a vector, i.e. the standard distance measurement in $R^2$.  The trouble is there seems to be some ambiguity with which norm I should be taking.  In any case I'm a little confused with where to go or what I've done wrong.  What I have:

Take a vector $v = [v_1, v_2]^T$ such that $|v| = 1$.  Then $Av = [3v_1 + 2v_2; v_2]$.  From here, I have $|Av| = \sqrt{(3v_1 + 2v_2)^2 + v_2^2} = \sqrt{9v_1^2 + 12v_1v_2 + 5v_2^2}$.  Am I on the right track?  If so, where do I go from here?  Tips appreciated.

Comment: What you are saying seems fine.  You might find it helpful to note that you can just as well maximize the norm squared to eliminate the root.  Then you are maximizing a quadratic in 2 variables subject to your constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Note that maximizing $|Av|$ is equivalent to maximize $|Av|^2$. Now, using $v_1^2+v_2^2=1$, it reduces to maximize $4v_1^2+12v_1v_2+5$ subject to the restriction $v_1^2+v_2^2=1$. We can solve it using Lagrange multipliers but it gets messy.

Another approach is as follows:   note that the matrix $A^tA$ is self adjoint and positive, and so there exists a unitary matrix $V$ such that $V A^tAV^{-1}$ is diagonal: $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   \lambda_1 & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda_2 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$
where each $\lambda_i\geq0$,and we may assume that $\lambda_1\geq\lambda_2$. Now,we
have

$\|A\|^2 = \sup\{|Av| : |v| = 1\}^2$

$= \sup\{|Av|^2 : |v| = 1\}$

$= \sup\{(A^tAv,v) : |v| = 1\}$

$= \sup\{(V A^tAV^{-1}v, v) : |v| = 1\}$

$= \sup\{\lambda_1v_1^2+\lambda_2 v_2^2: v_1^2+v_2^2=1\}$

$=\lambda_1$

It follows that $\|A\| = \lambda_1$, the largest eigenvalue of $A^tA$.
Which in this case is $7+2\sqrt{10}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate about the Lagrange multipliers?  I have the equation `F(x,y,\lambda) = (4v_1^2 + 12v_1v_2 + 5) - \lambda(v_1^2 + v_2^2 - 1)`

Comment: @user2049004 Let me add some details.

Comment: Actually solving this by Lagrange multipliers is not messy at all, it's completely equivalent to finding the eigenvalues of $A^tA$ when one realizes that solving $\nabla\mathcal{F}(v,\lambda)=0$ is equivalent to solving $A^tAv=\lambda v$ with $\|v\|=1$ :-).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Of course they are equivalent, but the direct computation gets a bit complicated.